# Can you not just send one push notification to Apple's Newsstand?

Tags: apple-push-notifications, newsstand-kit

We are developing a Newsstand app, and are currently working on the push notification to let users know a new issue has arrived. From the [ambiguous Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html) it looks like we will need to send a separate push notification for each user that downloaded the app; each notification should contain a unique device token for each app instance.

The section titled **Trust Components** seems to imply that you can use the device token *or* the certificates to authenticate your push notification, but it also implies you need both.

Is it correct that we will need to send out a separate push notification for each installed instance? Can we really not send *one* push notification and have Apple notify all the users of the app that a new issue has arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is YES the statement you made is correct.

You have to send out push notification to each device token which must be stored in your server (provider). The preferred way to send multiple notification is to not make multiple connections but reuse one to send multiple notifications. Below is the paragraph from [Apple Doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW2)

> You should also retain connections with APNs across multiple
>   notifications. APNs may consider connections that are rapidly and
>   repeatedly established and torn down as a denial-of-service attack.
>   Upon error, APNs closes the connection on which the error occurred